# Store operator and use directly?

Tags: c#

I.. just want to try to see if I can do with some new appounch.

I have a txt file with bunch of conditionals comparsion with values, i.e:

```
Parameter1!=Value2
```

Then I will read them and put each of them into my "Condition" object, and I will able to run the condition result to look put in Parameter1 and see if is not equal to Value2.

I just wonder if there is a type in C# that I cn store the conditon parameter?
So in the object there might define as:

```
operator InputOperator = "!=";
```

Then I can use it directly in the code:

```
if (Parameter1 ConditionObj.InputOperator ConditionObj.Value2)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

I know there is many other appounches, I just wonder if there is something like that exisits in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be talking about operator overloading but I think you got this the wrong way.

Comment: What types are `Parameter1` and `Value2` of? Just plain strigns?

Comment: actually the naming of Parameter1 and Value2 is kind of confusing... what it does do, is when my program read "Parameter1" this string in the text file, then I will take "Parameter1" and use the value.  So there is actually a.... int Parameter1 = 1; in somewhere of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you could easily do would be a delegate:

```
// Equivalent to Func<T, T, bool>, but the name probably helps explain
// the expected semantics better.
delegate bool ConditionOperator<T>(T left, T right)
```

Then you could use:

```
ConditionOperator<int> notEquals = (x, y) => x != y;
```

for example. Then you can pass around delegates as normal, and call them when you want to.

Comment: actually I am not looking for work around or new appounch, I just want to see if that's possible, but thanks for your code anyway.

Comment: @King: Well this is about as close as you can get, basically.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a mapping of `string => Func<object, object, bool>` delegates, and execute the appropriate delegate based on what's read in.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. I'd say the best bet is to use a method in ConditionObj for the comparison.